# arcpy.da.Editor undoOperation(): does it actually work

Tags: arcpy

Ok, so I have looked over the ESRI documentation thoroughly and I'm still baffled by the arcpy data access module and the function undo operation.

So far I have tried:

```
workspace = pathtofile      
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)   
edit.startEditing(with_undo = True)
edit.startOperation()
edit.isEditing
arcpy.CalculateField_management("MyTable", "LIFEFORM", 5000)
edit.isEditing
edit.undoOperation()
```

The undo operation does nothing and the undo button in the user interface indicates that it will remove the added layer, not the field calculate that I just performed.

I was hoping that I could implement the da.Editor into an addin toolbar as a way of avoiding the user from having to turn on an extension or start an edit session on a separate toolbar.

Comment: You need to use the Editor cursor to make the edits, not some other tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`undoOperation` is only supported if working with versioned data. As per the `arcpy.da.Editor` help: "Nonversioned edit sessions do not support undo and redo operations."